# htaccess redirects issue with old urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an old webseite made with php and all URLs have the same schema

```
domain.de/index.php?<sitename>
```

The first URL parameter is the sitename.

Now I want to redirect some of those URLs, how would a correct redirection look like that redirects only one of these pages and not all of them

Thanks in advance.

I tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?impressum /impressum
```

Example:

Old URL: `/index.php?oldurl`
New URL: `/newurlWithCompletlyDifferentURLName`

Update:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Die Anweisungen (Zeilen) zwischen „BEGIN WordPress“ und „END WordPress“ sind
# dynamisch generiert und sollten nur über WordPress-Filter geändert werden.
# Alle Änderungen an den Anweisungen zwischen diesen Markierungen werden überschrieben.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?impressum1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /impressum? [R=301,L]
```

Update
[image]

Comment: Also I don't see a point in removing OP's chosen original tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full .htaccess:**

```sh
# BEGIN WordPress
# Die Anweisungen (Zeilen) zwischen „BEGIN WordPress“ und „END WordPress“ sind
# dynamisch generiert und sollten nur über WordPress-Filter geändert werden.
# Alle Änderungen an den Anweisungen zwischen diesen Markierungen werden überschrieben.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?impressum1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /impressum? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

---

**Earlier Answer:**

This may work for you in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# all rules that have different redirect URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?oldUrl1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newurl1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?oldUrl2\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newurl2? [R=301,L]

# a generic rule that will redirect /index.php?foobar to /foobar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Please understand that `Redirect` directive doesn't support regex and it just matched starting URI. It cannot match query string.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/? /%{QUERY_STRING}? [R=301,NC,L]
```